# Win10 will no longer boot or restore after removing language pack

Tags: windows-10, boot, dism, language-pack, windows-pe

I've been following [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698742/how-to-change-windows-10-interface-language-on-single-language-version/31700488#31700488) to change the default language from Spanish to English on my Windows 10 Home Single Language edition (yes, I know, naughty). In a fit of frustration, I accidentally managed to delete the last language pack being used by the OS **and** reboot the PC. The horror.

Now the OS fails to boot even on Safe Mode and it also fails when attempting a clean restore. 
I believe there is a simple solution to this issue which involves installing the language pack I deleted from the command line, but I can't figure out how to go about it. 
I tried running "dism /Online /Get-Packages" and got this error message in Spanish:

*"DISM no admite la prestación de servicio a Windows PE con la opción /Online"*

Which roughly translates to:

*"DISM does not support servicing Windows PE with the /Online option"*

Could anyone knowledgeable in the matter help me sort this out?
I'm open to other solutions, whatever they might be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error and some furious googling I managed to do it exactly the way I suggested.

Here's the exact command I used for the trouble.

```
dism /Image:D:\ /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:/Users/Nacho/Downloads/Setups/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-us.cab
```

**"/Image:D:\"** refers to the drive letter which the Windows folder is located. For some reason on Windows PE my drive letters were reverted so D:\ is my OS drive while C:\ is my secondary drive.

You can check which one to use by running
dir C:\
If the Windows folder is on the list, that's the one. Else move on to D:\, E:\ and so on.

**"/PackagePath:..."** refers to the location of the package I had previously downloaded.

Hope this helps someone someday!

Comment: To add on to this, the `/online` option to `DISM` points it at your RUNNING INSTANCE of Windows. You'd use this if you were logged in. When working on a non-running instance of Windows, you have to point it to the install location, as you did with the `/Image` option.